# Calories not being recorded for HealthKit Watch app

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, healthkit

I can't get any calories/activeEnergyBurned to show up in my app, and don't know why?

`WorkoutInterfaceController`:

```
private func totalCalories() -> Double {
    return totalEnergyBurned.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())
}

private func setTotalCalories(calories: Double) {
    totalEnergyBurned = HKQuantity(unit: HKUnit.kilocalorie(), doubleValue: calories)
}

func startQuery(quantityTypeIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) {
    let datePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: workoutStartDate, end: nil, options: .strictStartDate)
    let devicePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: [HKDevice.local()])
    let queryPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[datePredicate, devicePredicate])

    let updateHandler: ((HKAnchoredObjectQuery, [HKSample]?, [HKDeletedObject]?, HKQueryAnchor?, Error?) -> Void) = { query, samples, deletedObjects, queryAnchor, error in
        self.process(samples: samples, quantityTypeIdentifier: quantityTypeIdentifier)
    }

    let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: quantityTypeIdentifier)!,
                                      predicate: queryPredicate,
                                      anchor: nil,
                                      limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                                      resultsHandler: updateHandler)
    query.updateHandler = updateHandler
    healthStore.execute(query)

    activeDataQueries.append(query)
}

func process(samples: [HKSample]?, quantityTypeIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self, !strongSelf.isPaused else { return }

        if let quantitySamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] {
            for sample in quantitySamples {
                if quantityTypeIdentifier == HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.activeEnergyBurned {
                    let newKCal = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie())
                    strongSelf.setTotalCalories(calories: strongSelf.totalCalories() + newKCal)
                    print("NewKCal: \(newKCal)")
                    print("TotalCalories: \(strongSelf.totalCalories())")
                }
            }

            strongSelf.updateLabels()
        }
    }
}
```

The log prints out '0' no matter how long I run the app for.

I've tested on the Simulator and on Device.

**Per a question, here is the code for saving workout data**:

```
private func saveWorkout() {
    // Create and save a workout sample
    let configuration = workoutSession!.workoutConfiguration
    let isIndoor = (configuration.locationType == .indoor) as NSNumber
    print("locationType: \(configuration)")

    let workout = HKWorkout(activityType: configuration.activityType,
                            start: workoutStartDate!,
                            end: workoutEndDate!,
                            workoutEvents: workoutEvents,
                            totalEnergyBurned: totalEnergyBurned,
                            totalDistance: nil,
                            metadata: [HKMetadataKeyIndoorWorkout:isIndoor]);

    healthStore.save(workout) { success, _ in
        if success {
            self.addSamples(toWorkout: workout)
        }
    }

    // Pass the workout to Summary Interface Controller
    WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames: ["SummaryInterfaceController"], contexts: [workout])
}

private func addSamples(toWorkout workout: HKWorkout) {
    // Create energy and distance samples
    let totalEnergyBurnedSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.activeEnergyBurned(),
                                                   quantity: totalEnergyBurned,
                                                   start: workoutStartDate!,
                                                   end: workoutEndDate!)


    // Add samples to workout
    healthStore.add([totalEnergyBurnedSample], to: workout) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        if success {
            // Samples have been added
            print("Samples have been added")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you save it ?

Comment: @Sandeep I added the code above for how I save the data.  Let me know if you have any thoughts or need me to add anything else!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it another way without using predicate.

```
weak var delegate: WorkoutSessionManagerDelegate?
let healthStore: HKHealthStore
var workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession 
var workoutStartDate: NSDate?
var workoutEndDate: NSDate?
var queries: [HKQuery] = []
var activeEnergySamples: [HKQuantitySample] = []
var distanceSamples: [HKQuantitySample] = []
var heartRateSamples: [HKQuantitySample] = []
let energyUnit = HKUnit.calorieUnit()
let distanceUnit = HKUnit.meterUnit()
let countPerMinuteUnit = HKUnit(fromString: "count/min")
var anchor = HKQueryAnchor(fromValue: Int(HKAnchoredObjectQueryNoAnchor))
let activeEnergyType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!
let heartRateType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)! // 1/3

var distanceType: HKQuantityType {
    if self.workoutSession.activityType == .Cycling {
        return HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling)!
    } else {
        return HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)!
    }
}

var currentActiveEnergyQuantity: HKQuantity
var currentDistanceQuantity: HKQuantity
var currentHeartRateSample: HKQuantitySample? 

init(context: WorkoutSessionContext) {
    self.healthStore = context.healthStore
    self.workoutSession = HKWorkoutSession(activityType: context.activityType, locationType: context.locationType)
    self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: self.energyUnit, doubleValue: 0.0)
    self.currentDistanceQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: self.distanceUnit, doubleValue: 0.0)

    super.init() 
    self.workoutSession.delegate = self
}

// MARK: Active Energy Burned Streaming
func createActiveEnergyStreamingQuery(workoutStartDate: NSDate) -> HKQuery? {

    print("Active energy query started")

    // ** Creating a match samples predicate to sum the data is no longer the convention **

    // Sum the new quantities with the current active energy quantity.
    guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) else {return nil}

    // Instantiate a HKAnchoredObjectQuery object with a results handler that calls our sumEnergyBurnedSamples function
    let activeEnergyQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: anchor, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, samples, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        guard let newAnchor = newAnchor else {return}
        self.anchor = newAnchor
        self.addActiveEnergySamples(samples)
    }

    // Results handler that calls our addActiveEnergySamples function
    activeEnergyQuery.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
            self.anchor = newAnchor!
            self.addActiveEnergySamples(samples)
    }
    return activeEnergyQuery
}


func addActiveEnergySamples(samples: [HKSample]?) {

    print("Updating calorie samples")

    guard let activeEnergyBurnedSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }

    // addActiveEnergySamples method dispatches back to the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 

        // Adds the new active energy sample to the running total
      self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity = self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity.addQuantitiesFromSamples(activeEnergyBurnedSamples, unit: self.energyUnit)

        // Adds that sample to an array of samples accumulated over the workout
        self.activeEnergySamples += activeEnergyBurnedSamples

        // Whenever new samples become available, call the corresponding delegate method. This updates the UI with new samples.
        self.delegate?.workoutSessionManager(self, didUpdateActiveEnergyQuantity: self.currentActiveEnergyQuantity)

        // Print checks
        guard let sample = activeEnergyBurnedSamples.first else{return}
        let value = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.energyUnit)
        print(value)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup. I recommend watching the video I was watching to see how the main class was done with initialization. Starts at about the 29 minute mark.  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/203/.  He uses predicate but you can just replace with the query block. There is also lots of code in my own questions. I added my init to my answer.

Comment: Did you watch the 2016 video? Wouldn't the way they do it in the 2016 video be more updated or no?

Comment: Not sure if I've seen the same one you have as there are many. My data is printing successfully to the console. I just have to send that data to my labels and make sure I'm storing data to the store and other details but the main part is done. It's been a lot of work and I needed a lot of help.

Comment: I think you should to watch this: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10009